# Is conditional expectation E(X|N) an a.e. equivalence class wrt N or underlying sigma algebra?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable defined on a measure space $(\Omega, F, P)$. Let $N$ be a sub sigma algebra of $F$.

Then conditional expectation $E(X|N)$ is an a.e. equivalent class. Is the a.e. relation   wrt $F$, or wrt $N$? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but: Given any two members of the equivalence class $E(X|\mathcal N)$, each is measurable with respect to $\mathcal N$, so the set where the members differ (which has probability zero) belongs to the sigma algebra $\mathcal N$.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible that $E(X|N)$ is the union of two disjoint a.e equivalent classes?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose you can always split a set with at least two elements into two disjoint subsets. But if all points in $\Omega$ have positive probability (i.e., $P(\{\omega\})>0$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$), then every conditional expectation is unique: the equivalence class contains just one element.

Comment: By equivalent class, I mean it wrt a.e. equivalent relation between random variables. It is not determined by me splitting, but by the underlying measure space with sigma algebra F or N.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what you mean, but again if $\Omega$ contains no singletons with positive probability, then $E(X|\mathcal N)$ is unique no matter what $X$ or $\mathcal N$ are...and one typically doesn't impose restrictions on $\Omega$ to rule out that possibility

Comment: E(X|N) is a set of r.v.s. If a random variable $Y$ is in $E(X|N)$, then any random variable that is equal to $Y$ a.e. must also  be in $E(X|N)$. That is, the a.e. equivalent class where $Y$ is in must be a subset of $E(X|N)$. My first comment is asking if $E(X|N)$ is just that one single a.e. equivalent class, or can it contain two or more different a.e. equivalent class(es) where some other class(es) don't contain $Y$? (I guess you know that the a.e. is a equivalent relation on the set of random variables, so the a.e. equivalent classes form a partition of the set of r.v.s.)

Comment: OK, I understand your question. Remember that every $Y$ in $E(X|N)$ has to be $N$-measurable, so there can exist a $Y'$ that equals $Y$ a.e. but $Y'$ is not a member of $E(X|N)$. In short $E(X|N)$ can be a proper subset of all variables that are equal a.e. to $Y$.

Comment: Can you show "there can exist a Y′ that equals Y a.e. but Y′ is not a member of E(X|N)"? I don't think so, because their integrals on any measurable set are same

Comment: On $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ let $P$ put mass $1/4$ on each of $1$, $2$, and mass $1/2$ on $3$. Let $N=\sigma(\{1,2\})$ and define $X=(2,0,0,0)$ [i.e., these are the values at (1,2,3,4)]. Then $Y:=E(X|N)=(1,1,0,0)$. But $Y':=(1,1,0,a)$ equals $Y$ a.e. but is not $N$ measurable if $a\ne0$.

Comment: Is E(X|N) exactly an entire a.e. equivalent class of N measurable functions? Or several such classes? Or part of such a class?

Comment: Part of. $E(X|N)$ consists of all N-measurable functions that integrate to the same value as $X$ does over any set in N. Every member of E(X|N) is a.e. equal to any other member. But the a.e. equivalence class for these functions will be a superclass of E(X|N) which can contain random variables that are not N measurable.

Comment: In my last comment, by a.e.equivalent class, I meant for the new measure space with N as sigma algebra. so  measurable functions are N measurable. In that new measure space, Is E(X|N) exactly an entire a.e. equivalent class of N measurable functions? Or several such classes? Or part of such a class?

Comment: Within the class of all $N$-measurable functions, all functions $Y'$ that are a.e. equal to $Y:=E(X|N)$ must also be members of E(X|N), since $|E(YI_B)-E(Y'I_B)|\le E|Y-Y'|=0$ for any $B\in N$.  So $E(X|N)$ is exactly an a.e. entire equivalence class.

Comment: In that new measure space, can E(X|N) be several a.e. equivalent classes of N measurable functions?

Comment: It's conceivable that you can specify a criterion to partition E(X|N) into disjoint classes. What would be the reason for doing so? And keep in mind that E(X|N) can be a singleton.

Comment: "It's conceivable that you can specify criterion to partition E(X|N) into disjoint classes" doesn't make sense. I guess you know that the a.e. is a equivalent relation on the set of random variables, so the a.e. relation partitions the set of r.v.s. into equivalent classes. it isn't what I can change. My last comment is a well defined question

Comment: E(X|N) consists of all variables that satisfy the definition of conditional expectation. Since we've established, in this new measure space, that every variable a.e. equal to Y is already a member of E(X|N), I interpret your question as asking whether E(X|N) can be *further* partitioned into disjoint subclasses. If that is your question, then how would these subclasses be different from each other? (You need a criterion to differentiate the subclasses, and the criterion can't rely on a.e. equivalence, or N-measurability.) If I am misinterpreting your question, you need to rephrase it.

Comment: Let me put it in another way: If Y1 and Y2 are both in E(Y|N), are they equal a.e. (wrt N)?

Comment: Yes. If $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are both N-measurable, then $Y_1=Y_2$ ae [$P$] if and only if $Y_1=Y_2$ ae [$P'$], where $P'$ is the measure on $(\Omega, N)$ defined by restricting $P$ to $N$. This follows from the fact that the set $Y_1\ne Y_2$ is an element of $N$.

Answer (score 0):

A conditional expectation is an equivalence class of random variables, which functions are defined on the sample space, not a $\sigma$-algebra.